# How can I say in one word "number written in words"?

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions, numbers

If there should be numbers written in words, like "one hundred and ten" instead of "110", how can I say it in one word?

Comment: I don't think there is a single word for this.  There are several words to describe different forms of numbers, e.g. _ordinal_ and _cardinal_, but nothing that just means "written in words", other than perhaps what Jim has suggested.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think the closest you can get is a hyphenated word:

> [*spelled-out*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/spell%20out) : 2. to write or print in letters and in full (numbers are to be *spelled out*)

Answer (score 6):

You may have said it best in your question: *in words*. After all, that's how several website tutorials describe it:

> This is the line underneath "Pay to the order of" where you write out, [in words](http://www.investopedia.com/university/banking/banking3.asp#ixzz2NhYhcPpw), the dollar amount of the check.
>
> Amount of check in words -- Enter the amount of the check [in words](http://west.salkeiz.k12.or.us/contract/kilfoil/NewKilfoil/Tech2/Accounting/info.htm). Start writing at the far left side of the line. Follow the dollar amount by the word "and," then write the amount of cents over the number 100. Draw a line from the end of the 100 to the end of the line.
>
> ...the different parts of the check (date, name and address of account holder, receiver of check or payee, amount in numerals, amount written [in words](http://mnliteracy.org/tools/reading-for-life/check-writing), memo line, signature, account information)
>
> Writing the amount of a check [in words](http://www.fremont.k12.ca.us/cms/lib04/CA01000848/Centricity/Domain/189/p8.pdf).
>
> The amount written [in words](http://checklookup.com/time.htm).
>
> The amount [in words](http://www.handsonbanking.org/htdocs/en/a/ba/chk/abachkpar.html) is written on this line.
>
> Amount of check: This should be written [in words](http://www.ed.psu.edu/educ/ppdc/caps/27caps.pdf).
>
> **Term**: written amount
> **Definition**: amount of check written [in words](http://quizlet.com/11968011/parts-of-a-check-flash-cards/)

Comment: For what its worth, *In words* is a far more common and appropriate choice than *Spelled-out*. Anybody remember Cashier's Cheques........

Comment: @Sayan Indeed.  It feels a bit clumsy, I think, but it is certainly the most commonly used way to express this.

Answer (score 0):

"Phobia" in one word. Jk.

Reality is that since we don't write checks anymore and the symbols are already embedded into buttons.

"Inscribe" is the word you maybe thinking of.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).